# How to edit linux kernel files?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, fork

I am working of fork function which creates a child process, I want to edit it in a way that whenever it is called it should print whether the process is created or not, (I am doing it just for practice, I know it is of no use).

What I have researched is this that fork function is defined in a file named fork.c which is in linux/kernel. I don't know that where is this folder in my ubuntu OS and also if I somehow get access to fork.c then will OS allow me to edit ?

I have also read that for this purpose I have to download another kernel and then edit the downloaded one with disturbing original (which is a headache).

I only want to edit fork.c in a way that it prints if a process is created or not.

Plzz ignore any useless stuff i have said, it would be great if you could give me the answer in steps to modify fork.c and then use it.

Comment: It sounds like you are already aware of the process for doing this, and no, there is not a shortcut.  This has been covered here many times before so it will most likely be closed as a duplicate.

Comment: Try `man strace`; `strace` is a program that traces system calls such as `fork()`.  There is no need to modify the Linux source.  You probably have `strace` installed; or run `sudo apt-get install strace`.

Answer (score 2):

So Linux has a helpful trick that you can use to do this in a **far** easier way. It's called [**`LD_PRELOAD`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick).

Using this trick, we can create a shared library that we inject into another process. This shared library will be able to run code before and after the call to `fork()`.

### Shared Library Code

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

static pid_t (*real_fork)(void);

pid_t fork(void)
{
    printf("Fork is called\n");
    if (real_fork == NULL)
        real_fork = (pid_t (*)(void))dlsym( RTLD_NEXT, "fork" );
    return real_fork();
}
```

### Demo Application Code

```
#include <unistd.h>

int main() {
    fork();
    fork();

    return 0;
}
```

### Showing how to put it all together

```
[10:19am][wlynch@apple preload] gcc -Wall test.c -o test
[10:19am][wlynch@apple preload] gcc -shared -ldl -fPIC fork.c -o fork.so 
[10:20am][wlynch@apple preload] ./test
[10:20am][wlynch@apple preload] env LD_PRELOAD=/tmp/preload/fork.so ./test
Fork is called
Fork is called
Fork is called
```